# What's the name of a series of under sea adventure books, about 1977

Tags: story-identification, books

There were questions and answers at the back about the story you just read. I think they had green or blue covers. Maybe geared towards boys but were exciting. Some had a submarine.

Comment: The Sea Quest series?

Comment: What about them was science fictional or fantastical?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/novel-with-rising-sea-levels-and-humans-live-on-rafts-and-communicate-with-whale

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the "[Hydronaut](http://www.biemiller.com/hyda.htm)" trilogy by Carl L. Biemiller written from 1970-1974?

I recently re-read these after reading them when they originally came out and they have held up surprisingly well.

> **The Hydronauts**:  *The range was not the entire world. But it was more than 80% of it,
> and all water. The nuclear war had long since melted much of the polar
> ice caps. Whole sections of continents were long gone. Hive cities had
> been set up under the surface of the water. Set in this world of the
> future, The Hydronauts tells of a team of marine wardens picked by the
> International Marine Counsel.*
>
> **Follow the Whales:** *The Hydronauts, Kim,
> Toby Lee, Tuktu and Genright Selsor are back together again for
> another futuristic adventure under the sea. This time Kim and his
> group receive special orders to become Sea Rovers, in search of the
> mankind created men-fish, who seem to be "managing" certain forms of
> sea life already under "management" by the Warden Service of the Hive
> Cities. Research has indicated that the best clues to the whereabouts
> and behavior of the men-fish may be by following the whale herds.
> Carrying out their orders to see if the men-fish should be allowed to
> live or not, the chase begins.*
>
> **Escape from the Crater:** *The four
> hydronauts revive a soldier preserved in ice since 1999, centuries
> before their time...* - <sub><sup>[Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385155360)</sup></sub>

As you can see from the covers, they do have a submarine as part of the adventures as well.

[image]

[image: Alternate Cover]

Answer (score 1):

Could it have been the Undersea trilogy by Pohl and Williamson?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersea_Trilogy